# Connect Multiple event to same method in c#

Tags: c#, events, methods, eventhandler

I have three event like this:

```
 public static event EventHandler BelowLowLimit;
 public static event EventHandler AboveHighLimit;
 public static event EventHandler PercentBelowLowLimit;

     protected virtual void OnThresholdReached()
    {
        EventHandler handler = null;
        if (rs.Value < rs.LowLimit)
        {
            handler = BelowLowLimit;
        }
        else if (rs.Value > rs.UpperLimit)
        {
            handler = AboveHighLimit;
        }
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

I have to raise event based on following condition:

```
public long Rs
    {
        get { return rs.Value; }
        set
        {
            if (rs.Value < rs.LowLimit)
            {
                OnThresholdReached();
            }
            else if (rs.Value > rs.UpperLimit)
            {
                OnThresholdReached();
            }
            else
            {

                this.rs.Value = value;
            }

        }
    }
```

What I want to connect this event to same method to raise the event. Is this correct way to do it?

please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: I do not see any *eventhandlers*. I see three *events*, one property which can trigger the firing of the events, and one method to actually fire on the three events. But no *eventhandler*. An eventhandler is a method that executes some code when an event *has been fired* IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at something like this?

```
        protected virtual bool CheckForThresholds(long rsValue, long rsLowLimit, long rsUpperLimit)
        {
            EventHandler handler = null;
            if (rsValue < rsLowLimit)
            {
                handler = BelowLowLimit;
            }
            else if (rsValue > rsUpperLimit)
            {
                handler = AboveHighLimit;
            }
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new EventArgs());
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public long Rs
        {
            get { return rs.Value; }
            set
            {
                if (!CheckForThresholds(value, rs.LowLimit, rs.UpperLimit))
                {
                    this.rs.Value = value;
                }
            }
        }
```